# Gulp dependant task not working properly

Tags: gulp, stylus

I have two gulp tasks, one to compile stylus files and the other is to clean my css files but I don't understand why **only clean-styles** run when I executed the command: **gulp styles** on the terminal.

```
gulp.task("clean-styles", function (done) {
    clean(config.css + "**/*.css", done);
});

gulp.task("styles", ["clean-styles"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.styles)
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css));
});

function clean(path, done) {
    del(path, done);
}
```

I"m using ***Gulp version 3.9.0*** I've done this on multiple project in the past and it seems to be working.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. There are no errors in the console.

Expected Result: 
I expect **styles** to run after the **clean-styles** task.

Actual Result: Only clean-styles run.

Comment: Which version of `del` are you using ? I'm looking at the [source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del/blob/master/index.js) now, and it doesn't seem like it uses callbacks anymore, juste the promise pattern.

Comment: @kombucha 2.0.2 version of del, ah that might be it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @kombucha for the heads up. It seems to be a change in the del package which caused this to no longer work.

```
gulp.task("clean-styles", function (done) {
    clean(config.css + "**/*.css", done);
});

gulp.task("styles", ["clean-styles"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.styles)
        .pipe($.plumber())
        .pipe($.stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.css));
});
```

**New Clean function:**

```
function clean(path, done) {
    del(path).then(function (paths) {
       console.log("Cleaning: " + paths);
       done();
    });
}
```