# npm del error in gulpfile Visual Studio 2015

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the del package in my gulpfile as part of a clean task.

Below are the the versions of things I'm using
Visual Studio 2015 Community
Node.js v2.11.3
gulp v3.9.0
del v2.0.2

This is an extract from my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var config = require('./gulp.config')();

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: true });

gulp.task('images', ['clean-images'], function () {
    log('Copying and compressing the images');

    return gulp
        .src(config.images)
        .pipe($.imagemin({optimizationLevel: 4}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build + 'images'));
});

gulp.task('clean-images', function (done) {
    clean(config.build + 'images/**/*.*', done);
});

function clean(path, done) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
    del(path, done);
}
```

When I run the task `images` from the command prompt using `gulp images` the `clean-images` task executes but never finishes.  It errors with the lines:

```
[16:10:45] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\**\Gulpfile.js
[16:10:46] Starting 'clean-images'...
[16:10:46] Cleaning: build/images/**/*.*
Process terminated with code 0.
```

As a result the rest of the `images` task doesn't execute.

The `images` task runs fine when I remove the `clean-images` dependency.

Don't suppose anyone has seen this issue before, and knows how to correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've encountered the same error as this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712873/gulp-dependant-task-not-working-properly#comment53273670_32712873) : the `del` module doesn't use callbacks anymore, but promises. `done` is never called, so the `clean` and `images` task run concurrently, which causes an error.

You could just return from the clean method :

```
gulp.task('clean-images', function () {
    return clean(config.build + 'images/**/*.*');
});

function clean(path) {
    log('Cleaning: ' + $.util.colors.blue(path));
    return del(path);
}
```

Comment: ah that explains it!  Thank you!