# Copy/Deletion in Gulp randomly gives ENOENT

Tags: gulp

New to Gulp. My `default` task is using the plugin`run-sequence` which tells task `deleteBuild` to run, then `makeBuild`.

Randomly, I am getting an `ENOENT` error which seems to be telling me that I'm either referencing files that don't exist for deletion or copy. My tasks are:

**deleteBuild**:

```
gulp.task('deleteBuild', function(done) {
  var del = require('del');
  del(['build/**/*'], done);
});
```

**makeBuild**:

```
gulp.task('makeBuild', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src(['src/**/*'], { base: 'src/' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/');
});
```

Can someone inform me as to how to best address this issue? I'm hoping to seek a low-level understanding rather than to be shown a solution w/o an explanation. Thanks.

***Aside***: I tried the `deleteBuild` without a callback function as well, under the assumption that, as is, it would perform the deletion and only continue to the next task once it is complete, though this doesn't seem to be what is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm del error in gulpfile Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743422/npm-del-error-in-gulpfile-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: So they're saying del() doesn't support callbacks? Correct me if I'm wrong, but if it returns Promises (something I'm not too solid on), then I need to add a 'return' to the del() plugin call so that Gulp only continues to the next task once that Promise is fulfilled?

Comment: It used to support callbacks, but it doesn't anymore. That's why there's so many snippets on the web showing it used with a callback...

And yep you can just return it and the task will end correctly :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`yo angular\` gives error: npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno 34 (yes I have cleaned the cache and set .npmignore)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964874/yo-angular-gives-error-npm-err-code-enoent-npm-err-errno-34-yes-i-have-cle)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the `deleteBuild` does not return a gulp stream and thus leave the pipe broken. I would propose the following:

```
gulp.task('deleteBuild', function() {
  var del = require('del');
  var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');

  return gulp.src(['build']) // no need for glob, just delete the build directory
    .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});

gulp.task('makeBuild', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src(['src/**/*'], { base: 'src/' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/');
});

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
  var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

  runSequence('deleteBuild', ['makeBuild'], cb);
});
```

These tasks will first delete the `build` directory before executing the `makeBuild` task.

You'll need to install one additional plugin:

```
npm install vinyl-paths
```

For a ready to use example, please take a look a the gulpfile of [skeletonSPA](https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA). This works for me ;-)